# ASP .NET CORE Background job

Tags: asp.net-core, cron

I want to add multiple background jobs to my projects. I am using ncrontab to schedule jobs. In my project, I have to trigger mail every 1 hour. if the application scales horizontally, will the trigger run many times?.

Comment: From your description, it seems that the Background tasks implemented in your application, if that is the case, if you scales the application, it will also scales the background jobs, so you might trigger the mail duplicate. You could consider creating a a microservice made just for hosting the IHostedServices (background jobs).

Comment: Since our project is a small application I would not like to change to a microservice. Are there any other options? Can we achieve this through quartz(DisallowConcurrentExecution) and hangfire?